# Trying to compare two strings in x86-64

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

```
global _start

section .data
    firstMsg: db "hello worms, please say the passcode", 10
    firstLen: equ $ - firstMsg
    secondMsg: db "Correct", 10
    secondLen: equ $ - secondMsg
    thirdMsg: db "Incorrect.", 10
    thirdLen: equ $ - thirdMsg
    password: db "Hello"

section .bss
    attempt RESB

section .data
_start:

;Print the first message
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, firstMsg
    mov rdx, firstLen
    syscall

;Read input
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, attempt
    mov rdx, 10
    syscall

;compare input to the password
    cmp attempt, password
    je L1
    jne L2
    syscall

;Display correct if correct
L1:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, secondMsg
    mov rdx, secondLen
    jmp L3
    syscall

;display incorrect if incorrect
L2:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, thirdMsg
    mov rdx, secondLen
    syscall

;exit the program
L3:
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 1
    syscall
```

This code returns this error message:

```
inout.asm:13: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
inout.asm:33: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

What I'm trying to do here is take input from a user as a string, which will then be compared to the constant password. If they are identical, it prints "correct", if they are not it prints "incorrect" and jumps back to the first question (not done that part yet).

If someone can help me bugfix this that'd be pretty cool.

Comment: Both operands to `cmp` are `imm64`s (pointer constants in your case), that's not a valid (let alone meaningful) comparison. Look into `rep cmps` instead. Plus, it doesn't seem logical to jump to `L3` unconditionally before you even executed your syscall. Also your definition of `attempt` in your BSS section is incomplete, it lacks a length and the label is missing the suffix `:`. And finally, I don't think it makes sense to put your code into your _data_ section... It should go into `.text`.

Answer (score 3):

a `cmp` instruction compares two values that fit into a register (8, 16, 32, or 64 bit values), not two strings.  You need a `cmpsb` to compare each character of the strings, and can use a `rep` with it to compare the whole string in one go:

```
;compare input to the password
    mov rsi, attempt    ; first string
    mov rdi, password   ; second string
    mov rcx, 5          ; length of the password
    repe cmpsb          ; compare
    jne L2              ; no match
    cmp byte ptr [rsi], 10  ; \n to end the input
    jne L2              ; extra stuff in attempt
    jmp L1
```

Note that you could simplify this a bit by adding the `'\n'` character to the expected password and using a length of 6.  Then you wouldn't need the extra cmp/jne checking for the end of the input.

Comment: Or with the password entry buffer zeroed to start with, a single qword `cmp qword [rel attempt], rax` instruction can check for equality.  (With a value in a register; not an immediate since the non-zero part of the string is longer than 32 bits).

Comment: @PeterCordes: you would need to pad-out the password properly to 8 bytes, but that could work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "buffer zeroed to start with".  The original source has `attempt RESB` which is either a syntax error or reserves no bytes, so that needs to get changed anyway, even if it happens to work to have an empty BSS that happens to link with that symbol address on some unused memory.

Comment: I'm not sure what rep is?

Comment: `rep` is one of the REP instruction prefixes (rep/repe/repne/repz/repnz) that can be applied to any of the string instructions (ins/outs/movs/lods/stos/cmps/scas).  It is short for "repeat" and repeats the string instruction until either rcx = 0 or ZF is set or clear (depending on which of the 3 possible prefixes is used).

Comment: Alright i think im beginning to understand. what is the `cmp byte ptr [rsi], 10` line for though? im not sure i understand what you are doing here

Comment: That is to check that the next character after the end of the entered (attempt) password is a newline -- the read syscall will generally read up to (and including) the newline when reading from a terminal.  As mentioned, it could be removed by including it in the expected password string.  Without ths check, entering `HelloWorld` would match the password of `Hello`

Comment: i tried the line but it had the error message `"ptr" is not a NASM keyword` and `comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand`

Comment: the `ptr` is standard intel asm syntax for memory access size -- not sure what the equivalent in nasm is.  Maybe `cmpb [rsi], 10`?

Comment: i simply removed it and it seems to work. only problem is that if the password is incorrect, it fails to make a newline.
it also cuts off the t at the end of incorrect for some reason